# Correct Syntax for left join

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone tell me why this sql query does not execute?

```
SELECT t_ads.*, t_adpics.picfile, 
FROM t_ads 
LEFT JOIN t_adpics ON t_ads.adid = t_adpics.adid AND t_adpics.isevent = '0' 
LEFT JOIN t_featured ON t_ads.adid = t_featured.adid AND t_featured.adtype = 'A' 
WHERE (a.adtitle LIKE '%findandpost%' OR a.addesc LIKE '%findandpost%') 
AND a.enabled = '1' 
AND a.verified = '1' 
AND a.expireson >= NOW() 
AND a.paid <> '0' 
AND (t_featured.adid IS NULL OR t_featured.featuredtill < NOW()) 
GROUP BY t_ads.adtitle 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 50
```

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM t_ads LEFT JOIN t_adpics ON t_ads.adid = t_a' at line 4`

Comment: There's a trailing comma in your `SELECT` statement, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with you statement is you have extra comma before the `FROM` clause,

```
SELECT t_ads.*, t_adpics.picfile, FROM
                                ^  remove this comma
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `,`

change

```
SELECT t_ads.*, t_adpics.picfile, FROM
```

to

```
SELECT t_ads.*, t_adpics.picfile FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to put the condition AND `t_featured.adtype = 'A'`  in the WHERE clause and remove `,` before `FROM` keyword

```
SELECT t_ads.*, t_adpics.picfile
FROM t_ads LEFT JOIN t_adpics ON t_ads.adid = t_adpics.adid 
LEFT JOIN t_featured ON t_ads.adid = t_featured.adid 
WHERE (a.adtitle LIKE '%findandpost%' OR a.addesc LIKE '%findandpost%')
        AND a.enabled = '1' AND a.verified = '1' 
        AND a.expireson >= NOW() AND a.paid <> '0' 
        AND (t_featured.adid IS NULL OR t_featured.featuredtill < NOW())
        AND t_featured.adtype = 'A'
        AND t_adpics.isevent = '0'
GROUP BY t_ads.adtitle ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 50
```